# recover folder data like repository commit

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, file-management

I have mistakenly made changes some text file data inside the folder. So is there any way or tool by which i can get files of that folder unchanged till the particular date? Like repository commit or something. I am using windows 7.

Comment: The thing that is like a revision control system, is a revision control system. The trouble with revision control systems is that you have to start using them before you need them. You can not say, oops I forgot to turn on the revision control system, let us go back to a checkpoint yesterday and turn it on. So your question is does Microsoft's Windows-7 have a revision control system that is already on?

Comment: Only if you have [Previous Versions](http://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/) enabled or you have backups.

Comment: I don't have any backups or restore point. Neither turned on revision control system. Is there any way?

Comment: No, there isn't. It's like asking an insurer to sign an insurance contract the day after you smash your car. Of course unless said folder was inside Dropbox. :P